# Какой знак выбрать?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Уместно ли тире в этом сложном предложении? Или лучше отредактировать?

> Этайн, идя рядом с Мидиром, проводила ладонью по мелким восковым листочкам – самшит, который видел еще старых богов, окаймлял дорожки, ведущие к воротам.

Comment: Почему не «листочкам самшита»?

Comment: @shampar Вы всю фразу целиком попробуйте построить.

Comment: Полагаю, автор вопроса достроит, если не будет держаться за тире.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вместо тире я бы использовала скобки.
2. Внутри скобок сделала бы акцент на возрасте самшита — с помощью тире.
3. Заменила бы длинное "который видел ещё" на "ровесник". По смыслу — практически одно и то же, но компактнее и лучше воспринимается (как *мне* кажется).

**Этайн, идя рядом с Мидиром, проводила ладонью по мелким восковым листочкам (самшит — ровесник старых богов — окаймлял дорожки, ведущие к воротам).**

Comment: Как ни "крутил" я эту фразу, ничего лучшего, чем предложила Римма, не нашел.

Comment: Энергично потирая ручонки, автор утащил "ровесника". )))

Comment: Рада, что мое мнение Вам пригодилось.

Answer (score 1):

**Этайн, идя рядом с Мидиром, проводила ладонью по мелким восковым листочкам – этот самшит видел еще старых богов, окаймлял дорожки, ведущие к воротам.**

Это мысли героини о дереве, о его причастности к ушедшим временам. Предложение (фактически  дословный пересказ этих мыслей) дается в виде присоединительной конструкции.